# Python: Reading and processing many files in parallelized

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, parallel-processing

I want to speed up the entire pipe line that I coded. Starting point of the pipe line is reading large number of files from directory and processing them. I read them and create a dictionary for further processing purpose. I wonder if the reading part and the creation part of the dictionary can be done in parallel mode.

Lets say files have following structure:

```
<doc id="22223423235">
<relatedDoc score="-0.079590" />
<relatedDoc score="-0.134223" />
<relatedDoc score="-0.106678" />
<relatedDoc score="-0.183504" />
<relatedDoc score="-0.179214" />
<relatedDoc score="-0.044658" />
</doc>
```

After processing the file I put it in a dictionary where each file is a key of the dictionary:

```
  for filename in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(dir_path)):
    with open(os.path.expanduser(dir_path + filename), 'rb') as data_file:
      first_line = data_file.readline()
      t = generate_tuple(first_line)
      if id not in data_dict[id]:
        data_dict[id].append(tag_score_tuple)
      x = sorted(data_dict[id], key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
      data_dict[id] = x
```

How can I do this in parallel mode?

Basically what I am thinking is instead of sequential file reading, I should spin more than one thread and each thread handle one file. Then can dictionary be access by more than one thread?

I am currently trying to follow following guide: 
https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html is this the right way to go?

Comment: you could probably use multiprocessing.Manager https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager